# Android accidental button click on ViewPager swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an Activity with a ViewPager with 3 dynamically created Fragments.  Each page has numerous Buttons and ImageButtons that activate on their own onTouch..MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN.

The problem I'm having is that these buttons activate accidentally when am trying to swipe the ViewPager.

Can anyone recommend a way to keep this from happening?

Thanks
Josh

Comment: have you ever figured out a way how to deal with this? I am facing the exact same problem. Even using the OnClickListener it still triggers this listener instead of the swiping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using onTouch..MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN.

on the ImageButton I will make them implement;

```
.OnItemClickListener() /This ensures that only when clicked they will call the desired functionality, I suggest you to check it out this way and let me know.
```

Hope it helps, more info at; [The Documentation for OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Comment: This seems like a good option, but won't work due to application.  My buttons are set to perform a function as they are being held down.  For example, hold the button down and a light bulb turns on.  Let go of the button, light bulb goes off.

Comment: In that case you can use onLongClickListener see more at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html Hope it helps.


Once its fired you can "turn on the light bulb" and on release you can " switch it off"

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying NOT to trigger the button at all.  I am trying to swipe to the next page in the ViewPager without triggering it.

Comment: I want to be able to click the button when I am trying to, but not accidentally when I am trying to swipe.

Comment: Exactly so you need to remove your custom implementation of MotionEvent.ActionDown, because on swiping gestures you will trigger it, srry I have not gave you another full example I am from my phone commenting

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Sorry for the confusion above...I was reading your answer on my phone, and missed the LONG portion in OnLongClickListener.  After I caught that it all made sense.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the flow you are following is not really good, the button also has the business code to handle the ACTION_DOWN touch event and the parent (ViewPager) always need handle touch event to detect the scroll events, so button will handle the ACTION_DOWN touch event first and then pass the touch to ViewPager.

You can move the business code into the OnClickListener of Button or another way you should let the button intercept the touch event and don't pass it to ViewPager (Parent View).

This can be easy to handle by customize the Viewpager class and add a variable in the custom ViewPager like this :

```
private boolean mTouchEnable = true;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    if (!mTouchEnable) {
        return false;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(arg0);
}
```

The button will need a reference to the viewPager and set the mTouchEnable = false in ACTION_DOWN and true in ACTION_UP

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is not my goal.  I want the ViewPager to be swipeable AND the button to be clickable.  I just want to ignore the Button click for a split second until it decides if it's truly a click or a swipe of the ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

I did a `viewpager` of buttons and I was able to replicate the issue.

I solved to this way:

My buttons have a listener `OnClickListener`

```
optionButton.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
  // your code here
}
```

Then I add this button to my `customPagerAdapter`

In your `customViewPager` you have to override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
   super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
   if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
      return true;
   }
   else{
      return false;
   }  
 }
```

This code will intercept the `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` in child views (return true) and won't intercept `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` neither `onClick` event in the child views.